# Kohen flying over a cemetery?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, vehicles-transportation, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, cemetery-grave

Is there a problem with a kohen flying in an airplane that may fly over a Jewish cemetery? If so, how can a kohen be sure that a flight does not go over a Jewish cemetery?

Comment: I guess your question is because you saw [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/comments/1c4xkp/orthodox_jew_completely_covered_in_plastic_bag_on/)?

Comment: This seems complete: http://www.yated.com/kohanim-concerns-while-flying-to-and-from-eretz-yisroel.0-576-0.html

Comment: @Ariel. Yes, I saw that, but I was under the impression that there was no problem. Hence my question. (BTW, the links on that article are to things that have nothing to do with the content of the article)

Comment: @Ariel, that Yated article basically says that nobody knows the answer.

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QITAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebcache.googleusercontent.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcache%3AuU_Z9OcQOcwJ%3Awww.vbm-torah.org%2Farchive%2Fhalak62%2F10plane.rtf%2Bvbm%2Bwolf%2Bairplane%26cd%3D1%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Dus&ei=lkNoUeWDFobm0QG774GQCg&usg=AFQjCNFusmDuydJkxKHU8qIQyWJAKqVg0w

Comment: http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/691408/

Comment: http://www.elhamikdash.com/49876/%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D---%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A3-

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of issues:

1. A flying object/tent is not considered a tent to separate.
2. Something that is Mekabel Tum'ah cannot separate.
3. A Kohen may not put himself in a circumstance of Tum'ah upon which a Nazir would have to shave and start over Nezirus.

The fact that the airplane MAY fly over Jewish Graves would probably be because it's like flying over a Beis Haperas (which most Achronim permit nowadays [see Taz 4 & Shach 2 on Yore Dai'ah Siman 369]).

There is also a Sofek Sfeka:

1. Most Aronos have a Chlal Tefach
2. Even if there is no Tefach in a specific Kever, maybe that body turned into Rekev
3. Today we don't have Kohanim Meyuchasim (see Teshuvas Yaavetz 155).

Comment: Beis Haperas is a much weaker safek. With many of these flights you can be quite sure that you'll fly over a cemetery. Also, Rekev is still metamei, no? Note also that in Israel many cemeteries don't use Aronos so that safek may not be applicable, certainly it's hard to imagine rov graves are built that way.

Comment: @DoubleAA See the Yated article why it could (or not) work

Comment: @Shmuel Brin At this point in history when everyone does it and will continue doing it we have to look for a Limud Zechus and if we can't find one we're better off not saying anything then to come to a conclusion that everyone is sinning.

Comment: I don't know why Beis Haperas is a weaker Safek when it includes everywhere out of Israel. As far as being quite sure about flying over cemetery (besides the fact that it only applies to Jewish cemeteries - because Tumas Ohel of a non-Jews body is only Drabanan and a Nazir wouldn't have to start again) there is the Din that a pregnant wife of a Kohain may go into Ohel Hameis because of SS maybe the baby the baby is a Neifel and even if not maybe it's a girl, now can't we be quite sure that it's not a Neifel?  We actually say Rov women give birth to a Ben Kayama.

Comment: Rekev is only Metamei if the body was buried naked and in marble (basically if a particle of anything else would make it not Metamei).The Rov graves are Tefach etc. is brought about the Kevarim in Israel as well (albeit I'm time of Tanayim) but I don't know what they do there nowadays.

Comment: @MeirZirkind see the yated article re Rov graves. He says they start out that way but it collapses after some time

Comment: @MeirZirkind "better off..." Since when do we say Mutav sheYihyu Shogegim on a Deoraita? And on some of the flights, it isn't a safek. It's a vadai. The air traffic control systems are sometimes very particular. And while the Shach does bring that sefeik sefeika, not all agree to it and certainly many other reasons to be meikil have been suggested.

Comment: I did NOT say Mutav at all, what I was saying was WE are better off being quiet (and not make every Kohen a sinner) and let the Rabbonim decide.

Comment: As for what you ask, since when do we say Mutav by Deoraysa? Please see the Tosfos Bova Basra 60b s.v. Mutav. Also see Sidei Chemed Vol. 6 page 384 he quotes Kneses Hagdolah who says we even say Mutav by a Din of Kareis.

Comment: Wait, why does an enclosed flying object not separate a kohen from the impurity emitted by the cemetary, but a plastic bag does?

Comment: Who said a plastic bag does?! Some random story in the Jewish Press is not a source of a Halacha to be able to use as an absolute truth to ask your question; You may ask why does a plastic bag separate a kohen from the impurity emitted by the cemetery, but an enclosed flying object does not? But the answer is that the general opinion is that plastic is not Mekabel Tum'ah but all metals are Mekabel Tum'ah, the only question is whether it could 'block' a person in it.