# Aeroplane flying over a cemetery as ohel

Tags: kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

For those who argue that a Cohen can fly over a cemetery in an aeroplane because the floor of the ‘plane functions as an ohel and blocks the impurity from reaching the passengers, how do they avoid making the floor of the ‘plane an ohel for people on the ground?

Eg if a Cohen is standing well outside a cemetery, but a ‘plane overhead is partly over him and partly over the cemetery, then surely if it’s an ohel he’s now tamei?

Comment: You realize the chances of this happening are so extremely small. The kohein would have to be standing within ~100ft of the cemetery at exactly the right time. Why do you suspect they feel any need to " avoid making the floor of the ‘plane an ohel for people on the ground?"

Comment: Please reference who it is who argues that a Cohen can fly over a cemetery in an aeroplane because the floor of the ‘plane functions as an ohel.

Comment: related or  dup: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27872/kohen-flying-over-a-cemetery?rq=1

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Various responsa quoted in this article: https://www.sefaria.org/Contemporary_Halakhic_Problems%2C_Vol_V%2C_Chapter_XII_Kohanim_and_Flights_Leaving_Israel.1 - in particular Teshuvot Kappei Aharon 25 and 50, relying on an opinion of the Ritva.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok That's an interesting thread but certainly not a duplicate. I'm asking not about whether the 'plane shields those above it, but about why it doesn't convey tumah to those beneath it.

Comment: You haven't provided any reason to think that it doesn't. You're asking for something that there's no reason to think should exist. This is like asking "how did George Washington catch COVID-19"; I can't answer that since as far as I know he didn't. Give some reason to think "they avoid making the floor of the ‘plane an ohel for people on the ground" and then you can ask how they do so.